# Value of date duration in "New user" of GA4

Tags: time, google-analytics, user-input, google-analytics-4

What is the **value** of the '**specific date duration**' in the '**New User**' definition in **GA4**? Initially, I believed it represented a fixed time period, but upon further investigation, I discovered otherwise. I conducted an experiment by creating a table with a time duration of 1 month (November 2022) and recorded the number of new users. Subsequently, I extended the duration to 4 months (August, September, October, and November) and captured the number of new users per month. Surprisingly, when comparing the number of new users in November 2022 in both tables, they were identical.

I repeated the comparison on a daily basis and obtained consistent results. Logically, increasing the time duration from 1 month to 4 months should result in a decrease in the number of new users, as there is a possibility that a person visited the website more than 1 month ago. However, this was not the case.

I am perplexed by this discrepancy and would appreciate any insights into what might be causing this unexpected outcome.